# Confidence interval on difference of estimates, given CI function for estimates

Tags: confidence-interval

Suppose we have independent random variables $X_i$, and we assert a parametric model of $X_i \sim f(\theta_i)$ that (given a sample of data {$x_i$} from one variable) has both an MLE function $\hat{\theta_i}(x_i)$ and a confidence interval formula for the MLE like $P(u(x_i) < \hat{\theta_i} < v(x_i)) = \gamma$.

Without further knowledge of the model, can we construct a function for the confidence interval on a comparison of estimated parameters for two such variables – whether the comparison be a difference like $\hat{\theta_1}-\hat{\theta_2}$, a ratio like $\frac{\hat{\theta_1}}{\hat{\theta_2}}$, or something similar?

Comment: Are you willing to assume normality (or a Student-t) for the sampling distribution of the $\hat{\theta}_i$? Are the $\hat{\theta}_i$ independent or is there a variance-covariance matrix for them that has non-zero off-diagonal elements?

Comment: If you can derive variance from CIs, then you can utilize the fact that variance of sum of random variables is sum of variances

Comment: @Björn I just edited to note that all variables (and estimates) are independent.  Assume that sampling distribution of the parameter can be non-normal.

Comment: @GAMer I can't see that: we would expect the variance on a difference of estimates to be lower than the variance on each estimate, but definitely not in a linear way.  Like if the variance on two estimates' CI is the same, the variance on the difference of estimates can't be 0.

Comment: @GAMer Often with MLEs the covariances of the estimates are appreciable, so for CIs of differences (or any linear combination) one uses the full covariance matrix (usually estimated from the Fisher Information matrix).  Adding the variances is incorrect.  The ratio is tricky (especially when $\hat\theta_2$ has some chance of being close to zero); under *some* circumstances the Delta method works.  There are *lots* of examples here on CV.

Comment: It's certainly not free from assumptions, but the method of variance estimates recovery (Donner & Zou 2012, doi:10.1177/0962280210383082) will allow you to create the desired confidence intervals from the individual estimates' confidence intervals. Their simulations (for what that's worth) show it's quite competitive against the delta method.

Comment: @PBulls Are you sure about the doi?  That paper is only about "Closed-form confidence intervals for functions of the normal mean and standard deviation," not about MLEs generally.

Comment: @whuber the paper contains specific examples and simulations for those & I believe it's where the name originated, but the approach applies generally to the difference, ratio, or product of two MLEs and their confidence intervals. They do have earlier papers (with the same methods & no mention of normal variables) at doi:10.1002/sim.3095, and see for example doi:10.1177/0962280213502144 for more discussion on ratios/products. I can't make strong claims on the method's appropriateness, but it certainly is quite straightforward and seems to perform well enough.